# How do you set the encoding for console output in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, cypress, console.log

[image]

My Cypress test output in CI looks like this everywhere. Is there a variable I can set to be able to read this more clearly?  The output should also be colored, I'm guessing that matters too.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Dealing with the same exact thing

Comment: my issue was more a docker issue I think, but this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920377/how-do-i-fix-console-log-encoding-issues-on-azure-ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it for me it was a combination of two issues:

1. I used `docker-compose` and had to change my command to be
   `docker-compose --no-ansi up`

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1865#issuecomment-337775040

2. I set the `NO_COLOR=1` ENV to have cypress turn off colors

[How do I fix console log encoding issues on Azure CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920377/how-do-i-fix-console-log-encoding-issues-on-azure-ci)

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1748

[image]

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!