# How do I fix console log encoding issues on Azure CI?

Tags: azure, docker, continuous-integration, cypress, console.log

I'm getting this on Azure CI when running Cypress in a docker container in a release pipeline.  I'm guessing it could be because of some setting in Cypress, docker, NodeJS, or the CI itself.

[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFHnv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFHnv.png)

I tried the `NO_COLOR=1` Cypress option in the pipeline, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variables set in the pipeline will not be active inside the Docker container. The Docker container has its own set of environment variables. 
I believe you will be able to resolve your problem by adding

```
ENV NO_COLOR=1
```

in the Dockerfile

Comment: this works much better, fixed the encoding for the actual output - but I still have stuff like this around the logging  ```[36mcypress_1  |[0m```

Comment: Same here. When we added the NO_COLOR option, there are still some of these left around the build log. I think we'll need to add a a ansi color plugin to Azure to fix this for the whole log. But the test report is fully readable now so we're not prioritizing it.

Comment: We're using ```docker-compose up``` and putting ```--no-ansi``` before ```up``` in addition to the above made it all work perfectly